# Painting with Ctrl Left Mouse in the Image Editor doesn't respect selected secondary color

Tags: texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

In a bare-bones scene in blender 3.6.4, I have the default binding to image paint with "Stroke Mode: Inverted" (using the secondary color) as `Ctrl Left Mouse`.

[image: The Blender keybinds menu. "paint.image_paint" with Stroke Mode: Invert is bound to Ctrl + Left Mouse]

This works as intended in the 3D Viewport in Texture Paint mode; I can paint with the selected Color (red) using `Left Mouse`, and with the selected Secondary Color (blue) using `Ctrl Left Mouse`.

[image: The Blender 3D viewport. A black cube is painted with a smiley face: half red, half blue.]

When attempting to recreate this behavior within the Image Editor in Paint mode, though, both `Left Mouse` and `Ctrl Left Mouse` paint with the selected (primary) Color.

[image: The Blender Image Editor. The same cube is unwrapped, this time painted with an entirely red frowny face.]

Is this intended behavior or a bug? I know there are workarounds such as using `X` to swap the primary/secondary colors, but is there a way to get a standard behavior across the two views?

Comment: Doesn't sound like an expected behavior to me. I would use the menu Help > Report A Bug.